# How come the compiler can't tell the result is an integer

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, modulus

I came across this funny behavior of the compiler:

If I have

```
    public int GetInt()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        double d = rnd.NextDouble();
        int i = d % 1000;

        return i;
    }
```

I get an error of:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

which actually makes sense as `1000` can be a `double`, and the result of the `modulo` operator might be a `double` as well.

But after changing the code to:

```
    public int GetInt()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        double d = rnd.NextDouble();
        int i = d % (int)1000;

        return i;
    }
```

The error persists.
As far as I can tell, the compiler has all of the information in order to determine that the output of the `modulo` operator will be an `int`, so why doesn't it compile?

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense anyway

Comment: The output of the modulo operator will be a double, since one of its operands is a double.

Comment: @harold The code is just a demonstration.

Comment: OK, then what is it that you actually want to know?

Comment: As I said: `why doesn't it compile?` It has all the information for knowing that the output is an Integer.

Comment: It knows that `i` is an integer, why should `d % 1000` be an integer? Even if the compiler has Special Magic Knowledge of Random.NextDouble (and it doesn't), then it would still have to conclude that `d %  1000` is a `double` in the range [0.0 .. 1.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if d is == to 1500.72546 then the result of the calculation int d % (int)1000 would be 500.72546 so then implicitly casting to an int would result in a loss of data.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. See C# language specification:

> 7.3.6.2 Binary numeric promotions
>
> Binary numeric promotion occurs for the operands of the predefined +,
>   –, *, /, %, &, |, ^, ==, !=, >, <, >=, and <= binary operators. Binary
>   numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common type
>   which, in case of the non-relational operators, also becomes the
>   result type of the operation. Binary numeric promotion consists of
>   applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type double, the other operand is converted to type double.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler *can* tell the result is an integer here, but is being your friend.

Sure, it can automatically convert it for you and not tell you about it and in your trivial example this would be just fine.  However, given that converting a `double` to an `int` means a *LOSS* of data, it might well have not been your intention.

If it had not been your intention and the compiler had just gone ahead and done the conversion for you, you could have ended up in a marathon debugging session, devoid of sanity - trying to figure out why a rather esoteric bug as been reported.

This way, the compiler is forcing you to say, as a programmer, "I know I will lose data, it's fine".

Comment: The compiler *can't* tell it's an integer at all since the result of double%int is a double.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

The result of a modulo of a double will be a double. If you need an integer result, then you must:

```
int i = (int)(d % 1000);
```

But bear in mind that you are liable to lose data here.

---

As I slowly engage my brain here - your code doesn't make any sense. `NextDouble()` will return a value between 0 and 1. There are some logical issues with what you are doing, the result will always be zero, e.g.:

```
0.15 % 1000 = 0.15

Cast 0.15 to int (always rounds towards zero) -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will assume you don't want to loose precision of the operation and implicitly use double.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
  double d = rnd.NextDouble();
  int i = d % (int)1000;
```

This code doesn't makes sense. `(int)1000` says 1000 is int, but `d % (int)1000` says that oh `d` is double, so compiler has to convert both into a common type [Binary numeric promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018156/2530848) mentioned in another answer to make it work.

One thing to understand is that you can't apply any operations with different types, so compiler will convert implicitly for you if there is no loss of data. So `(int)1000` will be **still converted to double by the compiler** before applying operation. so the result will be of type `double` not `int`.